# How do I auto reload API info to a Discord bot?

Tags: python, reload, discord.py

I am currently messing around with Discord bots, and am wondering if I can auto reload [this](https://hastebin.com/nofixuqiqa.py) every, lets say, 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.loop.create_task(loopPlaying(bot))

async def playingLoop(bot)
    while True:
        r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/')
        for coin in r.json():
            await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='BTC Price: $' + (coin["price_usd"])))
            await asyncio.sleep(15)
```

What the code above does is define a function to update the price every 15 seconds. Then, when the bot starts, the bot creates a background task using the new function